# How to query with SUM and WHERE between by date, but the row still there

Tags: mysql

How to query SUM field total and WHERE between mydate but the row still there, just change value total to be 0. Please check my explanation below:

I have two table the name is **category_result** and **result_values**.

Below is structure and values from table **category_result**:

```
id       name   
1        One    
2        Two    
3        Three  
4        Four   
5        Five
```

Below is structure and values from table **result_values**:

```
id_category_value       mydate         total
1                       2013-04-24     2
2                       2013-04-25     3
3                       2013-05-10     1
4                       2013-06-20     8
5                       2013-06-21     3
5                       2013-06-22     2
5                       2013-06-23     2
```

My query now is:

```
SELECT c.name, SUM(rv.total) as total_all FROM category_result c
LEFT JOIN result_values rv ON c.id=rv.id_category_value 
WHERE rv.mydate >= '2013-05-01' AND rv.mydate <= '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY c.id
```

And will get the result as below :

```
name      total_all
Three     1
Four      8
Five      7
```

But what I want is not like it, I want to be the result out roughly like this:

```
name      total_all
One       0
Two       0
Three     1
Four      8
Five      7
```

So I wanted a name still be there, but if the where of the above mydate, so the names One and Two are not listed by mydate, so I want the value total_all in the rows to be null or 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try full outer join instead of left join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `Sum` query a nested query and `JOIN` it with the data

```
SELECT ct.name, ISNULL(s.total_all, 0) FROM category_result cr
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_category_value, SUM(rv.total) as total_all FROM result_values  
  WHERE rv.mydate >= '2013-05-01' AND rv.mydate <= '2013-07-01'
  GROUP BY c.id
) s rv ON cr.id = s.id_category_value
```

And `Where` statement can be moved out.

Comment: Hello @Karel, Thanks for help me, but get error "#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'"

Comment: SOLVED I change ISNULL(s.total_all, 0) to s.total_all. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to move your where clause into the join. Otherwise this will exclude all category_results without a date:

```
SELECT c.name, COALESCE(SUM(rv.total),0) as total_all 
FROM category_result c
LEFT JOIN result_values rv ON c.id=rv.id_category_value AND rv.mydate >= '2013-05-01' AND rv.mydate <= '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY c.id
```

Note that we use COALESCE otherwise the sum for One and Two will be null rather than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use another join.

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.total_all
FROM category_result t1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT c.id, SUM(rv.total) as total_all FROM category_result c
LEFT JOIN result_values rv ON c.id=rv.id_category_value 
WHERE rv.mydate >= '2013-05-01' AND rv.mydate <= '2013-07-01'
GROUP BY c.id
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```